# How to add Drag and Drop to Lightning Components?

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components

Can anyone recommend a javascript library that allows **drag and drop functionality (desktop and mobile)** and works in a lightning component? Maybe point me to a post or better yet, provide some sample code for the cmp and js files.

I've attempted to implement both the [Sortable](https://github.com/RubaXa/Sortable) and the [Interact](http://interactjs.io/) js libraries but while I don't get any errors, they don't seem to fire when I attempt to drag anything. No errors are appearing in the js console either. Running the sortable example in plain html works though.

It's almost like the js libraries are being ignored but I've gotten jQuery to work just fine in the component.

Comment: I'm not sure that's a good duplicate reference. The only answer doesn't provide any explanation, and it doesn't use a library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok Noe.T I hope the below code will fulfill your requirement

Component

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable">
    <aura:attribute name="startId" type="string"/>
    <aura:attribute name="parentId" type="string"/>

    <div class="div1" id="div1" ondrop="{!c.drop}" ondragover="{!c.allowDrop}">
        <img src="{!$Resource.Pic1}" draggable="true" ondragstart="{!c.drag}" id="drag1" width="88" height="31"/>
    </div>

    <div class="div2" id="div2" ondrop="{!c.drop}" ondragover="{!c.allowDrop}">
        <img src="{!$Resource.Pic2}" draggable="true" ondragstart="{!c.drag}" id="drag2" width="88" height="31"/>
    </div>
    <input type="button" onclick="{!c.MoveDiv}" value="Click Me" />
    <div class="div2" id="div3" ondrop="{!c.drop}" ondragover="{!c.allowDrop}"><span id="drag3"> </span></div>

</aura:component>
```

Controller

```
({
    allowDrop: function(cmp, event, helper){
        event.preventDefault();
    },
    drag: function(cmp, ev, helper){
          var parentId = document.getElementById(ev.target.id).parentElement.id;
        cmp.set("v.startId",ev.target.id);
        cmp.set("v.parentId",parentId);
    },
    drop: function(cmp, ev, helper){
        var drag = cmp.get("v.startId");
        var div = ev.target.id;
        var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
        fragment.appendChild(document.getElementById(drag));
        document.getElementById(div).appendChild(fragment);
        var c = document.getElementById(div).children;
        var x = document.getElementById('drag1').parentElement.id;
        var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
        fragment.appendChild(document.getElementById(c[0].id));
        document.getElementById(cmp.get("v.parentId")).appendChild(fragment);
    }
})
```

Style

```
.THIS.div1 {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 35px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.THIS.div2 {
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Dragula](https://github.com/bevacqua/dragula) is a nice option.

It's impossible to say what the issue was when you tried to use the other libraries, but I'd double-check the element selectors you're using for the drag and drop containers.  Remember that Salesforce prepends a string of parent element IDs to your IDs, so it may have been that the elements weren't being selected successfully.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out. I'm used to visualforce changing the dom ids but from what I can tell, that doesn't appear to be the case in lightning but I'll double check that too.

Comment: Does Dragula work with LockerService enabled?